# Can manifest.json be used to remap website asset paths, so that static assets can utilize content-hash's?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, public, static-files, manifest.json

I'm having trouble utilizing a [contenthash] for static assets and remapping the asset path with a manifest.json file.

In my project, using Webpack v5 and React, I have a lot of image files in the 'public' folder which I reference within my code e.g.

```
<img src="/img/home/desktop/image-hero.jpg" />.
```

These image files are copied to the 'dist' folder during production build, using the 'copy-webpack-plugin'. This all works fine without a [contenthash] and the website displays correctly for both development (webpack dev-server) and production (using 'http-server' to serve the files).

I have scoured for solutions and saw mentions of using 'webpack-manifest-plugin', or similar, to generate a manifest.json file, which can then be linked in the HTML . Within the manifest it contains key-value pairs, of the original asset path-name and the amended path you wish to map to e.g.

```
{ "img/shared/tablet/image.jpg": "img/shared/tablet/image.37743784743ba76b4130.webp" }
```

My website successfully gets the manifest.json file, however nothing seems to happen in regards to subsequent requests for asset files. All the requests return 404 and the GET requests are to the original path and not the mapped path with the [contenthash]. If I manually request the contenthash file in the address bar it is available and loads.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the power of manifest.json, but from my research it looks like this approach should work - resources were suggesting this kind of approach can be used for CDN images too. I'm open to other suggestions of how to go about adding [contenthash] to static assets whilst still being able to reference the absolute path as per above.

In my HTML template, within the head tag:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="assets-manifest.json" />
```

In my webpack.prod.js, within the plugins section:

```
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'public', to: '[path][name].[contenthash][ext]' }],
    }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'assets-manifest.json',
      publicPath: '',
      writeToFileEmit: true,
    }),
```

In the dist folder, within the assets-manifest.json file (a sample):

```
"img/home/desktop/image-hero.jpg": "img/home/desktop/image-hero.55c18e980adf7658ae26.jpg",
```

I have tried playing around with numerous combinations in the manifest file, such as prepending 'dist/' to one or both paths for example, but to no effect. All my image assets are present, correctly hashed and then referenced in the manifest values.

As per screen render and console, the result is 'http://1.2.3.4:56/img/home/desktop/image-hero.jpg 404 Not Found'.

Comment: Tried experimenting with a service-worker, which was successful in redirecting the fetch requests for images, however it doesn't seem ideal because you end up needing to refresh the page once the service-worker is functional in order to reattempt the image requests.

The only two options I can see now are either redirecting requests on the backend perhaps, or figuring out a way to inject the newly created content-hash paths back into the source files with webpack - webpack doesn't work with non-import/require absolute paths however.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution to your problem. There is no magic way that the manifest file solves this for you. You usually solve this by calling a function that does a lookup in the manifest file and take the value of the key (the app.js file perhaps, which becomes app.26263727363.js)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).